# Gethostbyname returns NULL after 1021th request

Tags: c

Hello I'm sending requests in cycle and then processing them, I have to make that until the program's not stopped by the user. I have to use UDP and after testing on localhost after 1020 requests I get error in gethostbyname, it returns NULL

```
int sockfd, portno, n, serverlen;
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
struct hostent *server;
portno = my_port;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
server = gethostbyname(my_host);
bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);

if (sockfd < 0) {
  error("ERROR opening socket");
}
if (server == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host as %s\n", my_host);
  exit(0);
}

bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
(char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
serverlen = sizeof(serveraddr);
n = sendto(sockfd, packet, myArraySize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, serverlen); 

if (n < 0) {
  error("ERROR in sendto");
}

n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, &serverlen);
if (n < 0) {
  error("ERROR in recvfrom");
}
```

I found nothing about this behavior, and if I'm not using the localhost then I get the error after just 120 requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely explanation is that each process on your system is only allowed to have 1024 open file descriptors at a time. 3 of those are reserved for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.

So the problem is that each time you call `gethostbyname`, you create a new `sockfd`, but the code doesn't `close` the socket when it's done with it.

Comment: Oh god I think I'm blind. Yes it was that, it was enough to close the sockfd